# Para que serve o seletor @media no CSS?

Tags: css3

Gostaria de entender para que serve o seletor `@media` no CSS, pois tenho encontrado em vários códigos e queria saber se tem uma especialidade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `@media` conhecido como **media-query** seria uma condição ao qual você pode especificar um equipamento, tamanho, resolução, formato, rotação, etc.

O uso é simples:

```
@media(<condição>) {
    <css desejado para a condição>
}
```

O `@media` dependendo do navegador suporta até funcionalidades a mais, por exemplo, suportados somente no IE10+:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    /*Aplica o estilo em navegadores IE10+ */
}
```

> Assim que possivel irei enumerar as propriedades para media-query exclusivas de cada navegador/motor

---

### Operadores lógicos

Você pode compor *media queries* complexos usando operadores lógicos, incluindo `and`, `only` e `not`.

- O operador `and` é usado para combinar múltiplas funcionalidades em uma mesma *media query*, requerendo que cada sequência de características, retorne verdadeiro na ordem para que a query seja verdadeiro.
- O operador `only` é usado para aplicar um estilo apenas se a query inteira for igual, útil para prevenir que navegadores antigos apliquem os estilos selecionados. Se você usar os operadores `not` ou `only`, você tem que especificar um tipo de media explícito.
- O operador `not` é usado para negar uma *media query* inteira.

Você também pode combinar múltiplas *media queries* em uma  lista separadas por vírgulas, se qualquer uma das *media queries* na lista é verdadeira, toda a instrução retorna verdadeira, isto é equivalente a um operador `or`.

---

### Tipos de `@media`

- `all` que rodará em qualquer dispositivo
- `print` irá rodar no preview de impressão e no momento de imprimir será renderizado como neste formato
- `screen` destinado a monitores convencionais
- `speech` destinado a sintetizadores de fala.

### Funcionalidades para o `@media`

- `width` - Largura do viewport
- `height` - Altura do viewport
- `aspect-ratio` - Em base do aspeto ratio da largura para a altura do view-port
- `orientation` - Orientação do viewport (geralmente baseado pela largura e altura)
- `resolution` - Densidade dos pixels do dispositivo
- `scan` - Funciona conforme o processo de escaneamento do dispositivo (por exemplo dependo do frames)
- `grid` - Se o dispositivo usa grid ou tela bitmap
- `update` - Com que frequência o dispositivo de saída pode modificar a aparência do conteúdo (Level 4 Media Queries)
- `overflow-block` - Como o dispositivo de saída manipula o conteúdo que transborda a viewport ao longo do eixo do bloco (Level 4 Media Queries)
- `overflow-inline` - O quanto o conteúdo que transborda a viewport ao longo do eixo em linha pode ser rolado (Level 4 Media Queries)
- `color` - Número de bits por componente de cor do dispositivo de saída, ou zero se o dispositivo não for "color-gamut" colorido. Alcance aproximado das cores que são suportadas pelo agente do usuário e pelo dispositivo de saída (Level 4 Media Queries)
- `color-index` - Número de entradas na tabela de pesquisa de cores do dispositivo de saída ou zero se o dispositivo não usar essa tabela
- `display-mode` - O modo de exibição do aplicativo, conforme especificado no membro de exibição do "manifest" (é um arquivo) do aplicativo da Web
- `monochrome` - Bits por pixel no dispositivo de saída é buffer de quadro monocromático, ou zero se o dispositivo não for monocromático
- `inverted-colors` - Conforme user-agent ou as cores invertidas do sistema operacional são subjacente ou não (Level 5 Media Queries)
- `pointer` - O mecanismo de entrada principal é um dispositivo apontador e, em caso afirmativo, quão preciso for (Level 4 Media Queries)
- `hover` - O mecanismo de entrada primário permite ao usuário passar o mouse sobre elementos (Level 4 Media Queries)
- `any-pointer` - Qualquer mecanismo de entrada disponível é um dispositivo apontador e, em caso afirmativo, qual for a precisão (Level 4 Media Queries)
- `any-hover` - Algum mecanismo de entrada disponível permite ao usuário passar o mouse sobre elementos (Level 4 Media Queries)
- `light-level` - Nível de luz do ambiente (Level 5 Media Queries)
- `scripting` - Se scripts estiverem ou não habilitados em seu navegador (por exemplo javascript), pode usar o `not` para informar que o site só funciona com JS ou habilitar alternativas acaso não tenha (Level 5 Media Queries)

---

**Nota:** As media-querys também podem ser aplicadas aos elementos `<link>`, por exemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)" href="arquivo.css">
```

E também podem ser aplicados em css adicionados por `@import`, assim:

```
@import url("fineprint.css") print; /*aplica no preview de impressão ou no momento de gerar a impressão*/
@import url("bluish.css") projection, tv; /*aplica em projetos e televisores, provavelmente segunda tela conectada*/
@import "common.css" screen, projection; /*aplica tanto na tela principal quanto em projetores*/
@import url('landscape.css') screen and (orientation:landscape); /*aplica na primeira tela desde que a orientação esteja em landscape*/
```

---

### Conclusão

Então `@media` vai muito além de largura e altura, com `@media` você pode combinar várias funcionalidades, operadores, criar condições especificas e obter efeitos variados conforme a necessidade.

Answer (score 6):

@media funciona para você determinar um estilo CSS para cada tipo de mídia que te interessar.

Os mais comuns de se ver são os `@media screen` e `@media print`, um é para determinas o CSS para telas e o outro para determinar um CSS apenas quando for imprimir a página.

Vc também pode ter um CSS apena para TV `@media tv`

A formatação básica seria assim

```
@media not|only mediatype and (media feature) {
    aqui vc coloca os estilos 
}
```

Mas vc também pode importar o CSS específico para o media query que quiser

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="mediatype and|not|only (media feature)" href="mystylesheet.css">
```

Os **and|not|only** servem para vc determinar que o CSS só vai influenciar ou não determinado tipo de midia.

*Aqui tem uma lista pra vc consultar os **media feature**:* https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Outro link de referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Veja um exemplo:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
      body {background: #ffffff}
}
```

Aqui quer dizer que **apenas** quando a Orientação da tela for na vertical e a largura em pixels da View Port estiver entre 481px e 1024px a cor de fundo vai ser branca.

Outro para impressão:

```
@media print {
      body {background: #ffffff, color: #000000}
}
```

Aqui o CSS só vai ser aplicado quando em modo de impressão e vai colocar o fundo branco e a fonte preta.